# Is typescript really backward compatible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have read quiet a lot about typescript recently since I am planning to convert a very large Node.js Express Mongodb project to use typescript instead of my current JS+Babel setup.

The problem is that, I have read typescript is backwards compatible, meaning my current JS code should be able to run if I run it as typescript code. My confusion starts here because just to try typescript out, I have renamed my `server.js` to `server.ts` and everything seems to break..

I am currently getting this error:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
       ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I have already installed the `@types/mongoose` package and I have the following `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "removeComments": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "target": "es5",
      "outDir": "build",
      "strict": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "include": [
      "src/back/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
  }
```

Just to make the code work, I tried commenting out the mongoose part, but when I do it complains about another import (moment) and it just keeps going until I have basically no code left...

I am using the following versions:

```
Node.js 10.16.0
Typescript 3.7.3
ts-node-dev 1.0.0-pre.44
```

and this is the command inside my `package.json` that I use to run the dev server.

```
ts-node-dev --respawn --transpileOnly ./src/back/server.ts
```

I have already looked at many other questions on SO and other websites with similar issue to mine but the solutions that I tried did not work for me.

Comment: We'd need to know more about your current setup to answer this for you. How are you currently using `import` in node.js? *Why* are you currently using `import` in node.js?

Comment: Essentially no. They say it's a superscript of JS, but that's easy to disprove with expressions that work in JS but not in TS: `new Date() / 1000`. There are arguments like "superset just means it's valid code, not that it'll run." But what matters to any user is that in practical terms, you can't just move JS code into a TS project and expect it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because `import` is not part of the native node.js, it works only if it is transpiled through babel or similar tool. This is reason it is not "backward compatible" just as it is.

However typescript supports `import` as well, this is what we have in our tsconfig for some of our typescript projects, maybe the `moduleResolution` will do the trick

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es2017",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "dist",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
          "*": [
              "node_modules/*",
              "src/types/*"
          ]
      }
  },
  "include": [
      "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_introduction says "ECMAScript modules are the official standard format to package JavaScript code for reuse." In what way is that not native nodejs?